# Webview embed vimeo issue

Tags: java, android, webview, embed, vimeo

I used [this example](https://github.com/akhgupta/WebviewVideo) to play embed videos from youtube, with youtube it works perfectly. When I try to use it with Vimeo embed video, `Play` button works like `Fullscreen` and `Play` button at the same time.

How can I change code, to make the `Play` button work correctly?

Comment: Please provide relevant code examples and show the work you have already tried.

Comment: @TommyPenner you can see all structure of the app here https://github.com/akhgupta/WebviewVideo/blob/master/src/com/example/webview/MyActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the Vimeo Player will always go fullscreen on mobile devices - inline playback is not yet enabled.

Vimeo will be enabling inline playback on mobile in the near future, but there's no ETA for that development.

Comment: Wow! You really solved my problem, i just changed webview UserAgent to desktop, and now everything is great!
(code for example)
String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4)  Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
 mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);